# Is there a literal (non-figurative) meaning of "to turn the corner"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, phrase-meaning

I'm editing a book, and the author wrote the following sentence (emphasis added):

> If she walked straight past the next six stands, then **turned the corner** at her right, then turned again, and then passed a couple of houses (made of carved‐out rock), she’d reach her destination.

The writer intends to refer to literal movement, but I'm not sure if *turned the corner* is a valid way to reference physical movement. According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20the%20corner), *turn the corner* means "to get past the most difficult area or period in something and begin to improve." I've looked in other dictionaries as well, including [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/turn--the--corner), [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turn-the-corner), and even [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn_the_corner), but none of them list the literal meaning.

Is there a definition of *turn the corner* that involves literal, physical movement as used when giving/receiving directions? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: The meaning of making a turn at a corner is not a set expression, but simple English. Dictionaries cannot specify how regular words go together when used in their regular fashion: Red apple will not be defined because it's just an apple of that color.

Comment: In this case, the writer means, *turned [a]round the corner*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin What's confusing to me is that _turn_ appears to be used in a transitive sense but refers to the movement of the one turning. However, maybe that is a valid definition of _turn_.

Comment: @Justin I see, that's clearer to me. Feel free to make an answer of it.

Comment: There are over 1 000 000 Google hits for "turned the corner and found" (I've not checked for false positives) and only a handful for what I'd choose, "turned round the corner and found". The metaphor probably never has 'round'. // 'Turn/ed the corner' is IMO best left as an idiom, with idiosyncratic grammar. 'Turn [the] X' perhaps doesn't occur with other X's (You _could_ stick a 'proverbial' in).

Comment: @Lambie Just made the change, lol. That said, if you can make a statement, you can make a sentence too, right? Regardless, _wrote_ is better, at least after I changed "writer" to "author."

Comment: Merriam-Webster has under "[turn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn)": "to bend a course around or about" example: "turned the corner at full speed".

Comment: It's okay but I prefer "turn right at the corner."

Comment: @StuartF Ah, there it is! Thanks. I plan for it to be "turned around the corner," but if the writer says anything, it's good to know that there is dictionary support for the original wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, *turn the corner* literally refers to turning [[a]round](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around#:%7E:text=get%20past%20%3A-,on%20or%20to%20another%20side%20of,-trying%20to%20find) the corner. The verb [*turn*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn) means "to bend a course *around* or about: *ROUND*", so the preposition "[a]round" is redundant in "turn *[a]round* the corner". Hence, *turn the corner* is the more common form. Compare "pass the statue" (pass *by* the statue) or "ride a horse" (ride *on* a horse). So *turn the corner* doesn't necessarily *only* have to have a [figurative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20the%20corner) meaning.

---

Further reading: *Cognitive Space and Linguistic Case: Semantic and Syntactic Categories in English* by Izchak M. Schlesinger (see the [*Deletion of prepositions*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Z9cGgx871i4C&pg=PA173&dq=%22turn+the+corner%22+meaning&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHt-e98uT4AhUGAYgKHZO7APs4FBDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22turn%20the%20corner%22%20meaning&f=false) section).

Answer (score 3):

I would say, **yes** there is such a non-figurative use of "turn the corner".
Since it is non-figurative, you do not need a separate dictionary listing, merely use the dictionary listings of "turn" and "corner".

Comment: This answer would be improved if you linked and quoted said dictionary definitions, e.g. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn